# How to implement `Unary function chainer` using python?

Tags: python

I am doing codewar, i can't win this challenge.
Here is the link:
http://www.codewars.com/kata/54ca3e777120b56cb6000710/train/python

This is my implementation, but there is an error 'TypeError: 'generator' object is not callable
':

```
def chained(functions):
    for f in functions:
        yield f

def f1(x): return x*2
def f2(x): return x+2
def f3(x): return x**2

def f4(x): return x.split()
def f5(xs): return [x[::-1].title() for x in xs]
def f6(xs): return "_".join(xs)

print chained([f1, f2, f3])(0)
```

**Note**: The reuslt `chained([f1, f2, f3])(0)` is `4`!!!!!

Here is the tese cases:

```
test.assert_equals( chained([f1,f2,f3])(0), 4 )
test.assert_equals( chained([f1,f2,f3])(2), 36 )
test.assert_equals( chained([f3,f2,f1])(2), 12 )
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj I have updated it.

Comment: `chained` returns a generator which needs to be iterated over.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of returning a generator, you need to return a function, which takes one parameter and applies it to each chained function.

Your calling syntax is:

```
chained([f1, f2, f3])(0)
```

This means you want `chained` to return something you can call with a single parameter. A function will do fine.

A function which will work is:

```
def apply(param):
    result = param
    for f in functions:
        result = f(result)
    return result
```

This calls each function with the result of the previous function call. To start with you use the initial parameter.

However, as you don't pass the list of functions to this function which only takes one parameter, you need to capture them some other way. You can define a function within a function, and it captures any local variables:

```
def chained(functions):
    def apply(param):
        result = param
        for f in functions:
            result = f(result)
        return result
    return apply
```

Defining function `apply` locally captures the `functions` parameter. Then we return the function so it can be called, essentially `apply(0)`:

```
>>> chained([f1, f2, f3])(0)
4
```

Comment: My solution was correct for the original question! Updated

Comment: It is right now, but i cann't understand your solutuion, could you give me some explaination>?

Comment: @BlackMamba Added some explanation.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `reduce` ...

This takes a list of functions and applies the value to each of the functions in turn. So, the first function will be taken, and will return a value. Then, the second function will be taken, and will be applied to the new value, ...

```
fs = [f1, f2, f3] 
print reduce( lambda val, f: f(val) , fs, 0 )
```

What you want is a function `chained` which returns another function that takes one variable. An example function that takes one variable (lets say `m`) is `lambda m: m*2`.

Now a function that returns another function that takes one value?

```
def retFunc(): return (lambda m: m*2)
```

so we just combine the above two ideas and have ...

```
def chained(fs):
    return (lambda m: reduce( lambda val, f: f(val) , fs, m))

print chained(fs)(0)
```

Here, `chained(fs)` takes a list of functions `fs` and returns the function `lambda m: reduce( lambda val, f: f(val) , fs, m)`. This is a function that takes `m` and `reduce`s all the functions in order.

So, `chained(fs)(0)`

becomes `(lambda m: reduce( lambda val, f: f(val) , fs, m))(0)`

becomes `(reduce( lambda val, f: f(val) , fs, 0))`

which is exactly the first expression ...

Answer (score 0):

A generator is supposed to be iterated over. Instead of:

```
print chained([f1, f2, f3])(0)
```

try:

```
for i in chained([f1, f2, f3]):
    print i(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use recursion and currying in order to solve the issue:

```
def chained(functions):
    def g(x): #curry the functions
        result = x 
        for f in functions:
            result = f(result) 
        return result
    return g
```

result goes through the following given the `test.assert_equals(chained([f1,f2,f3])(0), 4)
on first iteration x = 0 so,  result = 0. therefore iterating over the functions
result = f1(0) then result = f2(f1(0)) then result = f3(f2(f1(0))). we then return result
we call the function "g" in the "chained" function since we only defined it locally earlier.